# How to add roman numbers to the appendix pages in LaTex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, roman-numerals

is there a way to have roman numbers for the pages at the end of the article - like \bibliography{...}, \listoffigures and acronym-lists?

Currently they show up without any numbers :(

Cheers,..

Argh sorry - I was kind of incorrect I'm not looking for a way to change the page-numbers - I'm looking for a way to change the actual action-numbers...

So Index looks like:

```
1 Section
2 Section
  2.1 SubSection
  2.2 SubSection
3 Section
References
Figures
```

But I'm looking for:

```
1 Section
2 Section
  2.1 SubSection
  2.2 SubSection
3 Section
I References
II Figures
```

Comment: Has this issue been fully resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\pagenumbering{roman}` is how to have Roman numbers on pages in general.  You would want to specify that style before those sections.

Comment: @Michael Greene, not your fault but the OP edited to say that he does not want to change page numbering but rather, "chapter numbering" to roman. So this answer is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what style you're using, but assuming you want to start over from `i`, you might try

```
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

You may need a `\global` before the `\setcounter`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}` right after `\appendix` will change the numbering format of the sections in the appendix and yield the index shown in the (edited) question.

Comment: You may have to do more to obtain the result requested by the OP, since the References and List of Figures are typically typeset as a `\section*` (without numbering).

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to change the page style to show numbers `\pagestyle{plain}`, and then follow [@Michael's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010177/how-to-add-roman-numbers-to-the-appendix-pages-in-latex/2010187#2010187).